# How to implement an interface which already has some other interfaces in it?

Tags: c#, interface

the example looks like this:

```
interface IA
{
    ICollection<IB> Bs {get;set;}
}

interface IB
{
}


public class BBase : IB
{

}

public class ABase : IA
{
    public ICollection<BBase> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

The question is that, when I wanted to implement the interface `IA` with `BBase`, just as I did in `ABase`, an error occured. Is that to say I can only use `IB` instead of `BBase` to implement the `IA` in `ABase`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to make `IA` generic:

```
interface IA<T> where T : IB
{
    ICollection<T> Bs { get; set; }
}

interface IB
{
}


public class BBase : IB
{

}

public class ABase : IA<BBase>
{
    public ICollection<BBase> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

The implementation of an interface should exactly match its definition, so in a non-generic case you are expected to have `ICollection<IB> Bs {get;set;}` in `ABase` exactly, that is it may accept any of `IB` implemetations.

While when the interface is generic (`interface IA<T> where T : IB`), it's implementation should provide any `T` satisfying the given constraint (i.e. here some exact implementation of `IB`). Consequently `ABase` class becomes generic as well.

For more info read:

1. [Generic Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak.aspx)
2. [where (generic type constraint) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Comment: +1 - useful approach when it is acceptable. Changing interface signature to be generic may not work in all cases.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov agree..in this very case it seems to me that the OP is only starting to design

Answer (score 2):

You can't implement property by specifying different type for it - see [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx):

> To implement an interface member, the corresponding member of the implementing class must be public, non-static, and have the same name and signature as the interface member

In your particular case you either need to use `ICollection<IB>` as a type for property in `ABase` or follow Konstantin Vasilcov suggestion to use generic `IA<T>`.

If you can't go generic route consider making property in the interface 'get' - only. This way you'll be able to not provide setter in the class and validate all "add to to collection" operations by having custom methods to add item(s) to the collection.